# How to resample a timeseries of dataframe according to the actual timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe 'a' like this,

```
[In]  a
[Out]
                  0
date               
2014-01-28  10.1956
2014-01-29  10.6456
2014-01-30  10.4350
2014-02-07  10.8275
2014-02-10  10.9806
2014-02-11  10.9711
2014-02-12  10.8849
2014-02-13  10.3967
2014-02-14  10.5211
2014-02-17  10.7700
2014-02-18  10.5211
2014-02-19  10.9232
2014-02-20  10.5594
2014-02-21  10.3679
2014-02-24  10.5115
2014-02-25  10.2339
2014-02-26  10.1286
2014-02-27   9.9371
2014-02-28  10.2914
2014-03-03  10.4732
2014-03-04  10.3201
2014-03-05  10.3296
```

If I use resample to collect the last day of each month, the result is:

```
[In]  a.resample('M').last() 
[Out]
                  0
date    
2014-01-31  10.4350
2014-02-28  10.2914
2014-03-31  10.3296
```

As you can see, there is no '2014-01-31' and '2014-03-31' in the original index. I only want to keep the last date of each month from the original index. The result should be:

```
                  0
date    
2014-01-30  10.4350
2014-02-28  10.2914
2014-03-05  10.3296
```

How can I get the result like this? Btw, I have used 'BM' in resample and got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert index to column, use `on` parameter in `resample` with `last` and last reassign index by `date` column:

```
df = a.reset_index().resample('M', on='date').last().set_index('date')
print (df)
                  0
date               
2014-01-30  10.4350
2014-02-28  10.2914
2014-03-05  10.3296
```

Comment: OMG...I tried this but got incorrect answer. Thanks!

Comment: @xiaoluohao - Can you be more specific?